# NgxChartsModule import slows down the page load

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using `NgxChartsModule` in one of the modules which is lazy loaded. The import statement in the `example.module.ts` is causing severe impact in page load time.

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxChartsModule
  ]
```

I'm only using `bar chart` and `line chart`. Is there any way I can import just those two to improve the loading time. Or is there any other way to bypass this issue.

Comment: If you are open to it you can switch to using https://www.chartjs.org/ in lieu of ngxcharts. I've used it in multiple angular apps before.

Comment: How large is the data set that you are trying to chart ?